# DependencyObject does not handle equality on object properties well

Tags: c#, dependencyobject

I was confronted with a StackOverflowException that made me discover that DependencyObject does not handle equality correctly ?!

When the DependencyProperty is of Type `Object` it will allways use `Reference.Equals`. This causes to fire PropertyChanged everytime for strings and valuetypes when the same value gets applied.

If you take a look at

> DependencyObject.Equals(DependencyProperty dp, object value1, object
>   value2)

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,3453

```
/// <summary>
///     Helper method to compare two DP values
/// </summary>
private bool Equals(DependencyProperty dp, object value1, object value2)
{
    if (dp.IsValueType || dp.IsStringType)
    {
        // Use Object.Equals for Strings and ValueTypes
        return Object.Equals(value1, value2);
    }
    else
    {
        // Use Object.ReferenceEquals for all other ReferenceTypes
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(value1, value2);
    }
}
```

A simple way to reproduce:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ObjValue), typeof(object), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

public object ObjValue
{
    get
    {
        return GetValue(ObjValueProperty);
    }
    set
    {
         SetValue(ObjValueProperty, value);
    }
}

protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Property == ObjValueProperty) { /*Breakpoint here*/ }
}

...
ObjValue = 7;
ObjValue = 7;
```

So, is this desired behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug. Its just the way dotnet handles objects. It is same same if you try it without the context of DependencyProperties:

I created a small console application:

```
object v1 = 7;
object v2 = 7;
if (v1 == v2) Console.Write("are the same"); else Console.Write("are different");
```

I read "are different" in console. So generally, if objects are evaluated for equality then always by ReferenceEquals (even if they are boxed value types).